# 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80] why ??? please help

Tags: apt, server, package-management, sudo

```
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
```

Comment: That PPA stopped being supported in 16.04?  That should have run warning bells that it was risky to add, and wouldn't work.  PPA's are 3rd party, so security is on you (ie. check it supports your release, is well maintained, trustworthy etc...)  *Note: I only looked at first error than stopped looking...  Same applies with your other PPA, but not middle issue*